# Magento 2 - Remove large category image

Tags: magento2, category, phtml

I found the answer to this for Magento 1.x, but I can't find a 2.0x solution.

On my category pages, before the products are shown, there is a huge image, "category-image".

Does anyone know where the phtml file is that loads this image?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It would be great if you can share screen shot that may help me to understand which image of category are you talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this in your theme

> app\design\frontend\{packagename}\{themename}\Magento_Catalog\templates\category\image.phtml

If you don't find the file here then you can create your own with same name having content:

```
<?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory();
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" alt="' . $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" title="' . $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) . '" class="image" /></div>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_imgHtml;
    }
?>
```

and you can modify it as you want. :)

Magento uses fallback method so this file is initially placed in `Magento_Catalog::view/frontend/templates/category/image.phtml`
You can overwrite it in your theme.

Comment: Thanks so much for this help. I had found this file earlier, and assumed this was what I needed to change, but was unsure on how to completely remove the image without causing a broken link.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\category` and look for file `image.phtml`. This file is responsible to display Category image before rendering products. You can override this file in your magento designed theme, and can modify as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
and remove block with xml code

```
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```